# Showing the number of elements $x$ s.t. $x^3=e$ is odd

Tags: group-theory

Let $G$ be a finite group. We want to show:

1. the number of elements $x$ of $G$ such that $x^3=e$ is odd, and
2. the number of elements $x$ of $G$ such that $x^2\neq e$ is even.

I am not sure where to start. I don't see how being a cubed group element equal to the identity say anything about the number of such $x$ in the finite group $G$. Any pointers for a proof would be appreciated!

Comment: A hint for the first: given that $x^3=e$, can you find another element $y$ of $G$, different from $x$, with $y^3=e$? (bigger hint: consider the powers of $x$...)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint:** Consider the function $f:G \to G$ given by $f(x) = x^{-1}$.

Note that if $x^3 = e$, then $(f(x))^3 = e$.  Similarly: if $x^2 \neq e$, then $(f(x))^2 \neq e$.

Comment: @FabioSomenzi Yes! But we all know that $e \approx 3$ so I was approximately correct

Comment: How did I miss that approximation?